# Exibir eventos fullcalendar codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Olá! Quero recuperar os eventos do banco de dados e exibi-los no calendário. Podem me ajudar a fazer isso? Até o momento, possuo os seguintes códigos:

Model:

```
Public function obter_noticias()
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE noticias.id";
return $this->db->query($sql, array($_GET['start'], $_GET['end']))->result();
}
```

controller

```
Public function obter_noticias()
{
    $result=$this->Noticias_model->obter_noticias();
    echo json_encode($result);
    echo $this->db->last_query();            
    die();
}
```

No arquivo.js, estou utilizando o seguinte código

```
var base_url='http://localhost/ci_adminlte/admin';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //alert('Teste de carregamento FullCalendar');
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            //right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek,'
        },        
        editable: false,
    navLinks: true,
    //selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    events: base_url+'noticias/obter_noticias'
    });
});
```

Abaixo, segue minha tabela

```
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 data DATETIME NOT NULL,
 titulo TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 noticia TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 usuario_cadastro VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 usuario_alteracao VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 dt_cadastro DATETIME NOT NULL,
 dt_alteracao DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

Comment: Pra quê `echo $this->db->last_query();`?

Comment: Para testar as queries.

Comment: E como fica a resposta pro `JavaScript`? Truncada?

Comment: Truncado, sim!!

Comment: Mas aí não vai funcionar mesmo, campeão.

Comment: Mas toda função que exibe o renderiza o fullcalendar está neste arquivo.
Então, acredito que events, também tenha que estar neste código.

Comment: Como é? A função que renderiza o `fullcalendar` está no `controller`? Isso não é correto. O `controller` só deveria retornar o objeto `json`. A biblioteca `fullcalendar` vai só usar o objeto gerado pelo `controller` no seu `events`.

Comment: Não está no controller,
Está em um arquivo .js, chamado através da view.

Comment: E onde está a `VIEW`? Vc poderia salvar esse objeto numa variável e passar pra `VIEW` carregar no `JavaScript`. Já tentou isso?

Comment: Já tentei,
Da forma que tenho no exemplo acima, coloquei alguns events manualmente e assim aparece, mas quando tento popular através do banco de dados, não consigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Método do model que captura os dados do db*:

```
function obter_noticias() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY noticias.data ASC";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $array = $query->result_array();
        return $array;
    }
```

Método do `controller` que retorna o objeto `json`

```
function Test_Function(){
  $noticias = $this->model->obter_noticias();
  $obj = NULL;
  //The cat's leap: criar o objeto para a variavel 'events' 
  foreach ($noticias as $i) {
    $obj[] = [
        'title' => $i['titulo'],
        'start' => $i['data']
    ];
   }
   echo json_encode($obj);
   exit();
}
```

*javascript*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  //alert('Teste de carregamento FullCalendar');
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek,'
  },
  editable: false,
  navLinks: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  events: {
    url: 'dashboard/Test_Function',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
     value1: 'aaa',
     value2: 'bbb'
    },
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
     alert('Erro ao carregar eventos!');
    },
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ola, desculpe a demora, estava tentando aplicar a forma como fizeste.
Não consegui.
Acredito que a estrutura dos meus arquivos não permita que seja feito desta forma.
Exemplo: Eu não estou chamando o fullcalendario através de `<scritp>` na view, estou chamando através de um arquivo externo javascript.
E este não comporta PHP, por trabalhar em client-server.
Então, esto tentando utilizar JSON, sendo que, estou tentando chamar o controller e seu método através do javascript.

Comment: Então, neste arquivo javascript, eu tenho isto:
`events: {
               url: 'dashboard/Test_Function',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    value1: 'aaa',
                    value2: 'bbb'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Erro ao carregar eventos!');
                },     
            }`

Comment: e dentro do controller dashboard, eu tenho este código:
`function Test_Function()
    {        
        $data = array
        (
            array
            (
                'id' => 1234, 
                'title' => "Nome: Wagner",
                'start' => "2017-01-13"
            ),
        );       
        echo json_encode($data);        
    }`

Mas no console.log, obetenho isto: 
`POST http://localhost/ci_adminlte/dashboard/Test_Function net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`

Comment: Fiz assim porque você não mostrou o método que carrega a `VIEW`, apenas mostrou o método que devolve o objeto `json`. Dá pra usar um `helper` que vai instanciar o objeto de forma global, mas eu preciso saber como você está carregando o calendário.

Comment: Eu consegui carregar com sucesso.
precisei definir `$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;`em `/config/config.php` do codeigniter.

Minha função: `function Test_Function()
    {
        $data = array
        (
            array
            (
                'id' => 1234, 
                'title' => "Wagner Fillio",
                'start' => "2017-01-13"
            ),
        );        
        echo json_encode($data);
 }`

Comment: Agora, pode me ajudar numa função para pegar os dados do banco de dados?
Algo do tipo: 

`<?php 
$notices = $this->db->get('noticias')->result_array();
   foreach($notices as $row):
?>
{
 title: "<?php echo $row['titulo'];?>",
 start: new Date(<?php echo date('Y',$row['data']);?>, <?php echo date('m',$row['data'])-1;?>, <?php echo date('d',$row['data']);?>)
},
<?php 
    endforeach
?>`

Comment: Pera... Compressão? Resolveu o quê com compressão de resposta? Conseguiu carregar o quê? Onde? Tá confuso. Vc está usando um método para formar o objeto e outro para carregar o calendário, certo?

Comment: Carregar os dados do banco não é problema. A resposta já tem um exemplo que você pode usar no `model`. O problema é passar o objeto `json` para o `javascript` pra preencher o calendário.

Comment: Vamos lá:
Folhego...
Primeiro erro foi: `net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`. Então resolvi alterando a configuração do codeigniter `config/config.phpconfig/config.php` para FALSE

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51705/discussion-between-shutupmagda-and-wagner-filho).

Comment: Perfeito a sua ajuda!
Te agradeço demais...
Funcionou perfeitamente..